# Crystal Report value Convertion?

Tags: crystal-reports

i have to crystal report made from Dataset,and we  have to one formula  field
i wrote Add() but that formula field show cancatination like 10+20=1020
i realize they need to convert that field in sight formula how to overcome this one?
anybody help me ?

Advance wishes...

Answer (score 0):

You can try using CStr in the formula

```
CStr(10)+CStr(20)
```